# Error Authenticating Spotify - Bad Request

Tags: python, localhost, spotify

I'm having a hard time trying to authenticate my `spotify` app on `localhost`. I have my `redirect_uri` set as `localhost:8888/callback` (have also tried it with `http://`) at my developer account, but I get this error page when terminal prompts me to enter the URL I'm being redirected to.

I am running my server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888`, and entering at terminal `python script.py username`.

This is my Python script:

```
scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id='myId', client_secret='mySecret', redirect_uri='localhost:8888/callback')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

This is the log:

```
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 210, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried it without the port number?
So replacing

```
localhost:8888/callback
```

with this:

```
localhost:/callback
```

Comment: it worked, but we must change `localhost:/callback` to `127.0.0.1/callback`